# How to use CVS in TestComplete?

Tags: cvs, testcomplete, version-control

Please, tell where to find free SCC provider for CVS. Because TestComplete, as i have understood works only through SCC.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like TestComplete works directly with cvs.   All you need is `cvs.exe` per their [webpage](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/abs/operations/cvs/).  If you need a copy of cvs for windows, I recommend [Tortoise CVS](http://www.tortoisecvs.org/).

Answer (score 2):

[Jalindi Igloo](http://www.jalindi.com/igloo/) is free, but very outdated. [CVS SCC Proxy](http://www.pushok.com/soft_cvs_proxy.php) is newer, but I'm not sure if it's free.